# Vectorized function as output of matlabFunction

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to automatize a process in MATLAB. I have a symbolic function that has to be converted into an anonymous function.

Basically, I have something like this:

```
    syms x y z t
    var = [x y z t];
    f = x.^2+y;
    gf = gradient(f, var);
    gf_fun = matlabFunction(gf, 'vars', {var});
```

giving as output

```
    gf_fun =
    function_handle with value:
    @(in1)[in1(:,1).*2.0;1.0;0.0;0.0]
```

Now, I'd like to evaluate this *gf_fun* in several points at a time, but, of course, I got strange results, due to how *gf_fun* is written. For example, if I want to evaluate *gf_fun* in 6 (different) points simultaneously, what I get is

```
    rng('deafult')
    vv = ones(6,4);
    gf_fun(vv)
    ans =
    1.3575
    1.5155
    1.4863
    0.7845
    1.3110
    0.3424
    1.0000
         0
         0
```

instead of a matrix with dimensions 4x6, with each colomn being the evaluation of a single point.

I know that a workaround will be the use of a for loop, that is

```
    results = zeros(4,6);
    for i = 1:6
        results(:,i) = gf_fun(vv(i,:));
    end
```

but I must avoid it due to code performances reasons.

Is there a way to automatize all the process, having a matrix as output of *gf_fun* while evaluating different point at a time? So, basically, there is a simple way to replace the `0.0` and `1.0` in *gf_fun* with a more general `zeros(size(in1))` and `ones(size(in1))` automatically?

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Did you profile this? "code performance reasons" rarely demand a loopless solution nowadays (since R2016b the JIT engine has made loops about as fast as vectorised solutions).

Comment: Yes, I did. The vectorized solution (obtained by hand) is ~1.5x faster.

Comment: What do you mean "by hand"? Can you show the results of the profiling?

Comment: "By hand" means that I copied and pasted gf_fun, replacing each `0.0` and `1.0` with `zeros(size(in1))` and `ones(size(in1))` manually. I cannot show the profile now, because I am on a trip, but for 350 points to evaluate it is something like 22ms vs 30ms.